# SSE divrem memory store requirements

Tags: memory, simd, sse, intrinsics, icc

I'm searching for information on the `divrem` intrinsic sequences and their memory requirements (for the store).

These folks (check SSE and SVML to see the intel intrinsics doc) :

```cpp
__m128i _mm_idivrem_epi32 (__m128i * mem_addr, __m128i a, __m128i b)
__m256i _mm256_idivrem_epi32 (__m256i * mem_addr, __m256i a, __m256i b)
__m128i _mm_udivrem_epi32 (__m128i * mem_addr, __m128i a, __m128i b)
__m256i _mm256_udivrem_epi32 (__m256i * mem_addr, __m256i a, __m256i b)
```

On the intel intrinsics guide, it states.

> Divide packed 32-bit integers in a by packed elements in b, store the
> truncated results in dst, and store the remainders as packed 32-bit
> integers into memory at mem_addr.

```
FOR j := 0 to 3
    i := 32*j
    dst[i+31:i] := TRUNCATE(a[i+31:i] / b[i+31:i])
    MEM[mem_addr+i+31:mem_addr+i] := REMAINDER(a[i+31:i] / b[i+31:i])
ENDFOR
dst[MAX:128] := 0
```

Does this mean, `mem_addr` is expected to be aligned (as per `store`), unaligned (`storeu`), or is it supposed to be a single register output (`__m128i` on the stack)?

Comment: I couldn't find any canonical information on it but the assembly uses an unaligned store: https://godbolt.org/z/9szzjEo7c Also note that no compiler except Intel seems to implement these intrinsics

Comment: From the way the code looks, it also seems like the intended use is with a pointer to a local variable, since the result of the function is actually stored in ```xmm1```

Comment: @Homer512 Yes I think pointer to local is also the safest option (when in doubt, ptr to local).

Comment: addendum. Btw, MSVC now supports SVML, though I do not know yet how good that support is. Certainly obscure intrinsics. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-backend-updates-in-visual-studio-2019-preview-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alignof(__m256i) == 32`, so for portability to any other compilers that might implement this intrinsic (like clang-based ICX), **you should point it at aligned memory**, or just a `__m128i` / `__m256i` temporary and use a normal store intrinsic (store or storeu) to tell the compiler where you want it to go.

As Homer512 points out with an example in https://godbolt.org/z/9szzjEo7c , ICC stores it with `movdqu`.  But we can see it *always* uses unaligned loads/stores, also for deref of `__m128i*` pointers for inputs.  GCC and clang *do* use alignment-required loads/stores when you promise them alignment (e.g. by deref of a `__m128i*`).

The actual SVML function `call  QWORD PTR [__svml_idivrem4@GOTPCREL+rip]` returns in XMM0 and XMM1; the by-reference output operand is fortunately an invention of the intrinsics API.  So it will fully optimize away to pass the address of `__m128i tmp` and then store it somewhere.